# orbit of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the action of $GL_2$

Tags: group-theory

I'm wondering whether this question is wrong...

It says show that $\operatorname{orb}(p)$ where $p=[1,1]$ is the set $\{[x,y]: xy\neq0\}$ but if we apply the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

we get the vector $[1,0]$ which has $xy=0$.

Is it me or the book who is wrong or am I missing the point completely?

Comment: The orbit of a nonzero vector under GL is the set of nonzero vectors.  Maybe they meant $x^2+y^2 \neq 0$ or $x,y \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the book is wrong. It should be : 
$$\mathrm{orb}(p) = \mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}$$

Indeed, if $x$ is any non zero vector, you can find $A \in GL(\mathbb{R}^2)$ that sends $p$ to $x$ (this property is known as transitivity), and for any invertible $A$, $Ap \neq (0,0)$ since $p \neq (0,0)$.